# 3 category deep has "shop by" 4 deep does not and I need to find out why

Tags: magento

Menu structure

```
Default Menu
  - Movies
    - DVD
  - Gaming
    - Video Games
      - Console
      - PC
    - Board Games
```

When clicking on Categories down to 3 deep I will get a "Shop By" (left nav) with price ranges, Categories if there is a subcategory, etc... but if I go 4 deep it disappears

I originally thought it was because it was the last category in the chain, but it will show up (with no sub category) for `DVD`, but not for `PC`

I have gone into

```
{theme}/default/catalog.xml
{theme}/default/local.xml
{theme}/default/template/catalog/layer/view.phtml
```

along with several other files that I can't remember the name of off the top of my head, and changed (in the xml files)

```
<catalog_category_layered_nochildren translate="label">
    <label>Catalog Category (Without Subcategories)</label>
```

tried to edit the `view.phtml` file seeing if I could force it through

Any help getting it to display in the deepest level of my navigation would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have the anchor settings set correctly for the 4th level categories.
Go to `Catalog->Manage Categories`, select the category on which the filters are not showing up and in `Display Settings` make sure you have `Is Anchor` set to yes.

Comment: Thank you, that has been driving me nuts!